# How do I make naked if statements into a compiler warning in XCode?

Tags: xcode, compiler-warnings

We've inherited a codebase with a lot of naked if statements, like so:

```
if (some_condition)
    do_something();
```

Our house style forbids this, so I'd like (if possible) for it to be a compiler warning.  Can I do that in XCode, and if so, how?

Comment: No you can't.  You need to look at some reformatting tools that support Objective-C and reformat your code outside of Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

trojanfoe is right, there's no way to get a warning. You can check that by putting `-Weverything` in your "Build Settings" in "Other Warning Flags".

[Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) is a pretty good code beautifier for many languages, including Objective-C. The config takes some time to setup, for your if-statements you want:

```
# Add or remove braces on single-line 'if' statement. Will not remove the braces if they contain an 'else'.
mod_full_brace_if                        = force
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with ObjClean http://objclean.com/index.php